# Dynamics CRM - access property within a workflow on newly created entity

Tags: c#, workflow, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I'm creating a Dynamics CRM workflow assembly to be executed when a new Note is created on another record of any type.  I need to be able to access a property Prop1 on that newly created Note entity to accomplish other tasks.

Previously I've only accessed values that were input from a field or from the user, but never on a property of a newly created entity.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
This is regarding CRM 4.0.

**More information while I wait:**
Ultimately, this workflow assembly will create an email that contains a link to the parent entity of the newly created Note record.  The property I need to get is the AnnotationId.  Once the Note record is created, I will be retrieving the ObjectId and ObjectTypeCode based on the AnnotationId of the newly created Note.
(In case you were curious)

Comment: Can you specify what version of CRM your working with? There are differences between 3.0 and 4.0 for this.

Comment: Hey did you ever check out the additional GetNotes code? Was this working for you?

Comment: sorry about the delay, I had to put out fires elsewhere and just came back to this project.  Yes, this gave me a great lead to accomplish what I wanted to do.  Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so if your using 4.0 custom workflows and not 3.0 callouts, you should add a workflow assembly, and use the Context service and executing context of your workflow to pull the values from the new note.

See the example below on how to access a record using the context service and the ID of your current context of execution (that should be your note)

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The Execute method is called by the workflow runtime to execute an activity.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="executionContext"> The context for the activity</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected override ActivityExecutionStatus Execute(ActivityExecutionContext executionContext)
    {

        // Get the context service.
        IContextService contextService = (IContextService)executionContext.GetService(typeof(IContextService));
        IWorkflowContext context = contextService.Context;

        // Use the context service to create an instance of CrmService.
        ICrmService crmService = context.CreateCrmService(true);
        BusinessEntity newNote = GetNote(crmService, context.PrimaryEntityId);

        string noteAttrib;

         noteAttrib = newNote.Properties.Contains("AnnotationId") ? ((Lookup)newNote.Properties["annotationid"]).name.ToString() : null;

        return ActivityExecutionStatus.Closed;
    }
```

GetNotes method would be a standard query for notes by Id through a CRM service call,
here is an example slightly modified from MSDN to return a note:

```
private BusinessEntity getNote(ICrmService service, guid noteid)
{
  // Create the column set object that indicates the fields to be retrieved.
  ColumnSet cols = new ColumnSet();

  // Set the columns to retrieve, you can use allColumns but its good practice to specify:
  cols.Attributes = new string [] {"name"};

  // Create the target object for the request.
  TargetRetrieveAnnotation target = new TargetRetrieveAnnotation();

  // Set the properties of the target object.
  // EntityId is the GUID of the record being retrieved.
  target.EntityId = noteid;

  // Create the request object.
  RetrieveRequest retrieve = new RetrieveRequest();

  // Set the properties of the request object.
  retrieve.Target = target;
  retrieve.ColumnSet = cols;

  // Execute the request.
  RetrieveResponse retrieved = (RetrieveResponse)service.Execute(retrieve);
  return RetrieveResponse;
}
```

Comment: I want to thank you for this code sample, I really appreciate it.  I have one further question.  I'm not sure how to make a query for a BusinessEntity such as notes.  I've never written a workflow like this before.  Can you give me a hint regarding the inside of GetNotes()?   Thanks again.

Comment: Ok, I edited the code to show the GetNotes() function, hope that helps you out. Workflow assemblies are one of my favorite features of the MSCRM sdk.